# Как отобразить значения пересечения синусоиды в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Нужно получить 2 столбца на основе второго с числами. Эти значения идут синусоидой. Когда происходит пересечение 80 и значения уменьшаются до 20, пишем в новый столбец '1'. Когда происходит движение от 20 до 80, пишем в еще один столбец значение '2' (до момента когда оно выйдет за 80).

[Файлы](http://dropmefiles.com/vcqv2)

Ввод:

```
20200402    10.04901961
20200402    17.89215686
20200402    21.56862745
20200402    29.41176471
20200402    50.98039216
20200402    74.50980392
20200402    83.59133127
20200402    80.49535604
20200402    68.42105263
20200402    52.63157895
20200402    26.31578947
20200402    17.27395412
20200402    20.51282051
20200402    25.64102564
20200402    17.94871795
20200402    9.991158267
20200402    14.05835544
20200402    16.09195402
```

Итог:

```
20200402    10.04901961     2
20200402    17.89215686     2
20200402    21.56862745     2
20200402    29.41176471     2
20200402    50.98039216     2
20200402    74.50980392     2
20200402    83.59133127 1    
20200402    80.49535604 1   
20200402    68.42105263 1   
20200402    52.63157895 1   
20200402    26.31578947 1   
20200402    17.27395412 1   
20200402    20.51282051 1   
20200402    25.64102564 1   
20200402    17.94871795     2
20200402    9.991158267     2
20200402    14.05835544     2
20200402    16.09195402     2
```

Comment: как часто вы собираетесь перезадавать один и тот же воспрос? в прошлом вопросе вам дали ответ и написали комментарии. если я не ошибаюсь, на уточняющие комментарии вы не ответили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
mask1 = df[1].shift().fillna(50).le(80) & df[1].gt(80)
mask2 = df[1].shift().fillna(50).gt(20) & df[1].le(20)
df.loc[mask2, "new"] = 2
df.loc[mask1, "new"] = 1
df["new"] = df["new"].ffill()
```

---

Результат:

```
In [88]: df
Out[88]:
           0          1  new
0   20200402  10.049020  2.0
1   20200402  17.892157  2.0
2   20200402  21.568627  2.0
3   20200402  29.411765  2.0
4   20200402  50.980392  2.0
5   20200402  74.509804  2.0
6   20200402  83.591331  1.0
7   20200402  80.495356  1.0
8   20200402  68.421053  1.0
9   20200402  52.631579  1.0
10  20200402  26.315789  1.0
11  20200402  17.273954  2.0
12  20200402  20.512821  2.0
13  20200402  25.641026  2.0
14  20200402  17.948718  2.0
15  20200402   9.991158  2.0
16  20200402  14.058355  2.0
17  20200402  16.091954  2.0
```